# How do you set parameters in Phoca Gallery 3.2?

Tags: module-params, phocagallery

For some reason the Thumbnail creation has switched off.

Googling the issue reveals that I can just switch it back on in Parameters - but I simply cant find a link to parameters anywhere.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You should try contacting the developers themselves.

Try 'Components - Phoca Gallery - Control Panel - click on icon Options (Parameters) (you can find this icon in top right corner of your Joomla administration)'

Under Main > Pagination Thumbnail Generation - (Yes | No) Thumbnails will be generated only from images which will be listed in the Gallery list (more information about this parameter in Phoca Gallery User Manual)

Hope this helps.